# I'm having trouble having my code outputting a pyramid correctly

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm having trouble having my code outputting correctly. I have gotten it right except for the spaces part (first nested for loop).

```
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Top();
    }

    public static void Top() {
        for (int a = 1; a <= 5; a++) {

            for (int b = 1; b <= 5; b++) {
                System.out.print(" ");           
            }

            for (int c = 1; c <= a; c++) {
                System.out.print("/");              
            }

            System.out.print("**");

            for (int d = 1; d <= a; d++) {
                System.out.print("\\");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
    /**\
   //**\\
  ///**\\\
 ////**\\\\
/////**\\\\\
```

Comment: What are you trying to do *and*, **what's your question?**

Comment: You're not telling us what it's supposed to do, so it's rather hard to help.

Comment: Did you mean to bound your "spaces" loop with 5 instead of "a" like the others?

Comment: Sorry everyone, I'm new to this and coding in general. I tried to add what I want the output to be, but I got an error saying it wasn't code.

Comment: The output should look something like a pyramid left aligned, but I can't show the output here. The top should have 5 spaces, lower one should have 4, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
for (int b = 1; b <= 5; b++) {
```

to:

```
for (int b = 1; b <= 5 - a; b++) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick! Can you explain to me the logic of why this worked? I want to understand what I did wrong. I would upvote you if I could, but it says I dont have enough reputation

Comment: @EverythingAndNothing You can "Accept" the answer instead of upvoting, as you are the one who asked the question. That's even better than upvoting :-) See here: [How to accept an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/236725)

Comment: @EverythingAndNothing Well your loop was printing out the same number of spaces for every row of the pyramid (iterate from 1 to 5). Instead you need to decrease the number of iterations performed for each row linearly. First time 1 to 5, next time 1 to (5-1), then 1 to (5-2), and so on...

Comment: Ok, I kinda see. I didn't know you could add variables to the second part of the for loop statement in the parentheses. That's good to know. Thank you for the explanation!